# HTML and java script file load in same html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to load a java script file in a html file using object tag or any other way .
  my scenario is as follows .
   parent.html file contain two div inside which I am loading childOne.html and childTwo.html
   files using object tag.

My problem is i have to do some work using jQuery.js , which i have to include in both the 
  children html files. 
  What I want is some WAY by which i just include the jQuery.js in the parent.html and 
  the two children html file should take the JS file from parent.html .

Please suggest some way .

Comment: If you put jquery at the end of rendered page, you can use jquery in both files. You don't need to include jquery on every files

Comment: document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML= '<object class="objectClass" type="text/html" data="childrenOne.html" ></object>';                      This is the code how i am including html file . How i put it at the end.

Comment: You can put at the end of file which contains your above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<object>` elements are, in this context, second-class `<iframe>`s. Different documents are different documents and have their own JavaScript environments.

You can communicate between them through `parent` and `frames` (depending on in which direction you are going in… and some browsers might not uses the frames API for `<object>`).

In theory, you might be able to wait for the framed documents to load, then access `document.frames.frameid.contentDocument` and copy the jQuery object into it - but that would probably result in a big mess as you try to get it refer to the right `document` object.

Your best bets are to either:

1. Stop trying to treat your framed documents as part of the document framing them - they are independent. If they need to use jQuery then it is their responsibility to load it. *or*
2. Stop using frames and put the HTML content of those files in the top level document so they aren't independent

Answer (score -1):

You can just add the script tag with the jQuery file url into the parent.html file and it will work when children is loaded

if you do add jquery code to the child file make sure you instantiate jQuery in the file eg

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){});
</script>
```

if you do that the jQuery code will work

Comment: It will work in the parent document. It won't work in the child document (because its a different document). `$(function(){});` will not make jQuery code work. It will call a jQuery function that will cause the anonymous function you pass to it to be called then the DOM Ready event fires … *if* jQuery is loaded in the document you put that code in.